# nifi docker image can not identify docker-volume

Tags: docker, apache-nifi, docker-volume

I am trying to run `nifi-docker` image and put files to it.

I created a `docker-volume` as instructed in [comment section](https://www.nifi.rocks/official-nifi-docker-image/), and mapped to docker image.

`docker create --name nifi -v nifi-volume:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf -p 9090:8080 apache/nifi:latest`

`docker start nifi`

This works and I can access to web-gui. But when I try to create a process for `GetFile` and put `nifi-volume`, it can not get that folder.

> Directory does not exist

I have created `nifi-volume` using `docker volume create --name nifi-volume`

Comment: I am not sure but I think you are looking for [bind-mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) where you map host directory to container directory, which lets you modify files on host and modification will be visible inside the container.

Comment: @michalk do you suggest me to use `--mount` flag instead of `-v`?

Answer (score 1):

You have mounted:

```
nifi-volume:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf
```

That means nifi-volume is actually

**/**

or you have to create a folder inside 
/opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf called nifi-volume

```
mkdir /opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf/nifi-volume
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but how am I supposed to create a folder inside my docker container, as I do not use docker compose.

Comment: when you create a volume it maps to a folder inside your computer and that folder is /opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf/ this folder is on your local disk not inside the docker container